# Why are both wires white and black hot at the outlet, light switch and even at light in the ceiling. I replaced the outlets and switches and lights

Tags: wiring

Why are both wires white and black hot at the outlet, and light switch and even at the light in the ceiling

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. It isn't clear what you're asking; would you add pictures of the insides of the boxes involved? And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Comment: What are you using to test the wires for "hotness"?

Answer (score 1):

In the case of a light switch, it is normal if the switch is setup as follows:

```
[elec ]B=========#==============+
[panel]W--------+ +X---------X+ |        
                | |           | |   
                (~)           [-]
               light         switch
```

The white wire is carrying power back to the light, and convention dictates there should be a piece of black tape (X) around the white wire to indicate it is a live return.

It's important that the switch must go against the live lead not the neutral.

-- Minor edit to diagram.  The wire from the panel usually ends in the ceiling.  A new wire runs to the switch, black to black with a nut, and white (switched hot) back to the fixture. `#` indicates this nut.

Answer (score -2):

In all reality, there is no official distinction of what color wire is for what. However, common convention says the black = hot/powered/charged/incoming, white = neutral/return, green = ground/earth, and red = switched.

When it comes to 3/4 way switches, it's not uncommon to see 2 blacks, 2 whites, or each color as hot. Same for switched outlets or outlets running in parallel. If an inexperienced homeowner did any kind of rework, could also explain it.

Comment: Green/yellow-green/bare equating to earth/ground is a hard Code requirement.  Also, if neutral is present it must be white or gray.  White and gray can be reallocated to hots.